# How can I get the translated term with entityTypeManager in Drupal 9?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views

This is the code. How can I get `$tree` translated to the langage inserted in `$langage`.

```
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$tree = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('secteur', 0, 1, TRUE);
foreach ($tree as $term) {
    $id = $term->get('tid')->value;
    $result[$id] = $term->get('name')->value;
}
$variables['parentterms'] = $result;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`EntityRepository::getTranslationFromContext()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityRepository.php/function/EntityRepository%3A%3AgetTranslationFromContext/8.4.x) :

> Gets the entity translation to be used in the given context.
>
> This will check whether a translation for the desired language is
> available and if not, it will fall back to the most appropriate
> translation based on the provided context.

```
$entityRepository = \Drupal::service('entity.repository');
foreach ($tree as $term) {
    $id = $term->get('tid')->value;
    $result[$id] = $entityRepository->getTranslationFromContext($term, $language)
}
```

Also, since the language of the current context defaults to the current content language, you don't need to set `$language`.